# Not showing the newly created project to select, when creating new Agent in Google Dialogflow ES

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I created a new project in Google Cloud Console. (eg. `my-project-abc12345` - only a example name)

Then I tried to create an agent in Google Dialogflow Console, under the created project.

But the project `my-project-abc12345` I created is not listed here. Does anybody know a possible reason for this?

[image]

Actually, I need to create the project first as I need proper naming for my project_id, and then use it in the agent creation time in Dialogflow.

The same scenario works well with my personal google account. For this one, I am using my company's google account.

Your ideas/comments/answers on this are really appreciated.

Comment: Up-vote was given already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below steps to resolve your issue :

1. First, make sure that you are using the same account in GCP and in
   Dialogflow ES console, and that the account is listed as the owner
   for that project.
2. You can try refreshing the browser page with the Dialogflow ES console if the project was created after you opened the `Create a New Agent` option in Dialogflow ES.
3. You can create an agent via the
   API and then open it in the console, pasting the project ID in the
   URL to the agent in the browser address bar.That is, open an
   existing agent and replace the project ID in the URL.
4. The above step
   is not required if you can see the new agent in the agents selector
   after refreshing the Dialogflow ES console browser page.

Comment: I tried refreshing the browser and also with clearing the browser cache, waited for about 2-3 hours, and checked,  but the project did not appear. But I checked today (after about 2 days), and now the project is listed when creating Dialogflow Agent. Accepting this as the answer it is suggesting some useful points.